# assign integer order to decimal numbers

Tags: r, integer

I have 200 numbers all between 0 and 1. I would like to rank them and assign integer values 1-199. It could be something very easy to accomplish but i don't know which function to use - the order function does not really work.

say here is what I have:

```
    0.12, 0.56, 0.112, 0.8, 0.356, 0.00001
```

I want:

```
    3, 5, 2, 6, 4, 1
```

Thank you!!

Comment: I think you're looking for `rank`.

Comment: Or `order`:  rev( order(rev(c(0.12, 0.56, 0.112, 0.8, 0.356, 0.00001))))

Answer (score 9):

There is a built in function for exactly this purpose:

```
x <- runif(10)
rank(x)
[1]  7  3  8 10  4  2  5  1  6  9
```

see `?rank` for the options for dealing with ties.